# Get incremental counts of an aggregated value in a joined table

Tags: mysql, aggregate, mysql-5.7

I have two tables in a MySQL 5.7.22 database: `posts` and `reasons`. Each post row has and belongs to many reason rows. Each reason has a weight associated with it, and each post therefore has a *total* aggregated weight associated with it.

For each increment of 10 points of weight (i.e. for 0, 10, 20, 30, etc), I want to get a count of posts that have a total weight less than or equal to that increment. I'd expect the results for that to look something like this:

```
 weight | post_count
--------+------------
      0 | 0
     10 | 5
     20 | 12
     30 | 18
    ... | ...
    280 | 20918
    290 | 21102
    ... | ...
   1250 | 118005
   1260 | 118039
   1270 | 118040
```

The total weights are approximately normally distributed, with a few very low values and a few very high values (maximum is currently 1277), but the majority in the middle. There are just under 120,000 rows in `posts`, and around 120 in `reasons`. Each post has on average 5 or 6 reasons.

The relevant parts of the tables look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE `reasons` (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  weight INT(11) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `posts_reasons` (
  post_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  reason_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_posts_reasons_posts (post_id) REFERENCES posts(id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_posts_reasons_reasons (reason_id) REFERENCES reasons(id)
);
```

So far, I've tried dropping the post ID and *total* weight into a view, then joining that view to itself to get an aggregated count:

```
CREATE VIEW `post_weights` AS (
    SELECT 
        posts.id,
        SUM(reasons.weight) AS reason_weight
    FROM posts
    INNER JOIN posts_reasons ON posts.id = posts_reasons.post_id
    INNER JOIN reasons ON posts_reasons.reason_id = reasons.id
    GROUP BY posts.id
);

SELECT
    FLOOR(p1.reason_weight / 10) AS weight,
    COUNT(DISTINCT p2.id) AS cumulative
FROM post_weights AS p1
INNER JOIN post_weights AS p2 ON FLOOR(p2.reason_weight / 10) <= FLOOR(p1.reason_weight / 10)
GROUP BY FLOOR(p1.reason_weight / 10)
ORDER BY FLOOR(p1.reason_weight / 10) ASC;
```

That is, however, unusably slow - I let it run for 15 minutes without terminating, which I can't do in production.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

In case you're interested in testing the entire dataset, it's downloadable [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q3HZXW_qIZ01gU-Krms7qMJW3GCsOUP5).  The file is around 60MB, it expands to around 250MB.  Alternately, there are 12,000 rows in a GitHub gist [here](https://gist.github.com/ArtOfCode-/7e912ff19c724866ec2bc55601c8c0af).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using functions or expressions in JOIN conditions is usually a bad idea, I say usually because some optimisers can handle it fairly well and utilize indexes anyhow. I would suggest creating a table for the weights. Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE weights
( weight int not null primary key 
);

INSERT INTO weights (weight) VALUES (0),(10),(20),...(1270);
```

Make sure you have indexes on `posts_reasons`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ... ON posts_reasons (reason_id, post_id);
```

A query like:

```
SELECT w.weight
     , COUNT(1) as post_count
FROM weights w
JOIN ( SELECT pr.post_id, SUM(r.weight) as sum_weight     
       FROM reasons r
       JOIN posts_reasons pr
             ON r.id = pr.reason_id
       GROUP BY pr.post_id
     ) as x
    ON w.weight > x.sum_weight
GROUP BY w.weight;
```

My machine at home is probably 5-6 years old, it has an Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470 CPU @ 3.20GHz and 8Gb of ram.

uname -a
Linux dustbite 4.16.6-302.fc28.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May 2 00:07:06 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I tested against:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q3HZXW_qIZ01gU-Krms7qMJW3GCsOUP5

```
MariaDB [test3]> select @@version;
+-----------------+
| @@version       |
+-----------------+
| 10.2.14-MariaDB |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


SELECT w.weight
     , COUNT(1) as post_count
FROM weights w
JOIN ( SELECT pr.post_id, SUM(r.weight) as sum_weight     
       FROM reasons r
       JOIN posts_reasons pr
             ON r.id = pr.reason_id
       GROUP BY pr.post_id
     ) as x
    ON w.weight > x.sum_weight
GROUP BY w.weight;

+--------+------------+
| weight | post_count |
+--------+------------+
|      0 |          1 |
|     10 |       2591 |
|     20 |       4264 |
|     30 |       4386 |
|     40 |       5415 |
|     50 |       7499 |
[...]   
|   1270 |     119283 |
|   1320 |     119286 |
|   1330 |     119286 |
[...]
|   2590 |     119286 |
+--------+------------+
256 rows in set (9.89 sec)
```

If performance is critical and nothing else helps you could create a summary table for:

```
SELECT pr.post_id, SUM(r.weight) as sum_weight     
FROM reasons r
JOIN posts_reasons pr
    ON r.id = pr.reason_id
GROUP BY pr.post_id
```

You can maintain this table via triggers

Since there is a certain amount of work that needs to be done for each weight in weights, it may be beneficial to limit this table.

```
    ON w.weight > x.sum_weight 
WHERE w.weight <= (select MAX(sum_weights) 
                   from (SELECT SUM(weight) as sum_weights 
                   FROM reasons r        
                   JOIN posts_reasons pr
                       ON r.id = pr.reason_id 
                   GROUP BY pr.post_id) a
                  ) 
GROUP BY w.weight
```

Since I had a lot of unnecesary rows in my weights table (max 2590), the restriction above cut the execution time from 9 down to 4 seconds.

Comment: Clarification: This looks like it's counting _reasons_ with a weight lower than `w.weight` - is that right? I'm looking to count posts with a _total_ weight (sum of weights of their associated reason rows) of lte `w.weight`.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I'll rewrite the query

Comment: This got me the rest of the way, though, so thanks! Just needed to select from the existing `post_weights` view that I already created instead of `reasons`.

Comment: @ArtOfCode , did I get it right for the revised query? BTW, thanks for an excellent question. Clear, concise and with lot's of sample data. Bravo

Answer (score 7):

In MySQL, variables can be used in queries both to be calculated from values in columns and to be used in expression for new, calculated columns. In this case, using a variable results in an efficient query:

```
SELECT
  weight,
  @cumulative := @cumulative + post_count AS post_count
FROM
  (SELECT @cumulative := 0) AS x,
  (
    SELECT
      FLOOR(reason_weight / 10) * 10 AS weight,
      COUNT(*)                       AS post_count
    FROM
      (
        SELECT 
          p.id,
          SUM(r.weight) AS reason_weight
        FROM
          posts AS p
          INNER JOIN posts_reasons AS pr ON p.id = pr.post_id
          INNER JOIN reasons AS r ON pr.reason_id = r.id
        GROUP BY
          p.id
      ) AS d
    GROUP BY
      FLOOR(reason_weight / 10)
    ORDER BY
      FLOOR(reason_weight / 10) ASC
  ) AS derived
;
```

The `d` derived table is actually your `post_weights` view. Therefore, if you are planning on keeping the view, you can use it instead of the derived table:

```
SELECT
  weight,
  @cumulative := @cumulative + post_count AS post_count
FROM
  (SELECT @cumulative := 0),
  (
    SELECT
      FLOOR(reason_weight / 10) * 10 AS weight,
      COUNT(*)                       AS post_count
    FROM
      post_weights
    GROUP BY
      FLOOR(reason_weight / 10)
    ORDER BY
      FLOOR(reason_weight / 10) ASC
  ) AS derived
;
```

A demo of this solution, which uses a concise edition of the reduced version of your setup, can be found and played with [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88b042/5).

Comment: I tried your query with the full data set. I'm not sure why (the query looks ok to me) but MariaDB complains about `ERROR 1055 (42000): 'd.reason_weight' isn't in GROUP BY` if `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is in @@sql_mode. Disabling it I noticed that your query is slower than mine first time it runs (~11 sec). Once data is cached it is faster (~ 1 sec). My query runs in about 4 seconds every time.

Comment: @Lennart: That's because it's not the actual query. I corrected it in the fiddle but forgot to update the answer. Updating it now, thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @Lennart: As for the performance, I may have a misconception about this type of query. I thought it should work efficiently because the calculations would be complete in one pass over the table. Perhaps that's not necessarily the case with derived tables, in particular those that use aggregation. I'm afraid I don't have neither a proper MySQL installation nor enough expertise to analyse deeper, though.

Comment: @Andriy_M, it seems to be a bug in my MariaDB version. It does not like `GROUP BY       FLOOR(reason_weight / 10)` but accepts `GROUP BY reason_weight`. As for performance I'm certainly not an expert either when it comes to MySQL, it was just an observation on my crappy machine. Since I ran my query first all the data should already have been cached, so I don't know why it was slower the first time it ran.